# std::common_type not resolved correctly for MSVC and AppleClang

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, visual-c++, clang++

I have started writing my own [typesafe unit library](https://github.com/bigdavedev/units) targeting C++14. Primarily I develop on Linux so naturally my compilers are gcc and clang. I have gotten very far with this and have decided to expand this to other platforms (Windows and MSVC, OSX and AppleClang).

Trouble is that neither of these compilers will compile the following test code:

```
TEST_F(DistanceTest, OperatorRemainder_WhenGettingRemainderByDistance_WillGiveRemainder)
{
    auto const result = 2531_m % 1_km;
    EXPECT_EQ(531, result.count());
}

TEST_F(DistanceTest, OperatorRemainderInt_WhenGettingRemainderByDistance_WillGiveRemainder)
{
    auto const result = units::distance<int>{2531} % 1_km;
    EXPECT_EQ(531, result.count());
}
```

In MSVC I receive the following error:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\vs15preview\Common7\IDE\VisualCpp\Tools\MSVC\14.10.24516.00\include\type_traits(1246): error C2446: ':': no conversion from 'units::kilometres' to 'double' [C:\Users\david.brown\units\.vs\build\test\distance_ut.vcxproj]
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\vs15preview\Common7\IDE\VisualCpp\Tools\MSVC\14.10.24516.00\include\type_traits(1246): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
  C:\Users\david.brown\units\test\test_distance.cpp(171): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::common_type<double,units::kilometres>' being compiled
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\vs15preview\Common7\IDE\VisualCpp\Tools\MSVC\14.10.24516.00\include\type_traits(1247): error C2955: 'std::decay': use of class template requires template argument list [C:\Users\david.brown\units\.vs\build\test\distance_ut.vcxproj]
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\vs15preview\Common7\IDE\VisualCpp\Tools\MSVC\14.10.24516.00\include\type_traits(1056): note: see declaration of 'std::decay'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\vs15preview\Common7\IDE\VisualCpp\Tools\MSVC\14.10.24516.00\include\type_traits(1246): error C2446: ':': no conversion from 'units::kilometres' to 'std::ios_base::iostate' [C:\Users\david.brown\units\.vs\build\test\distance_ut.vcxproj]
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\vs15preview\Common7\IDE\VisualCpp\Tools\MSVC\14.10.24516.00\include\type_traits(1246): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
  C:\Users\david.brown\units\test\test_distance.cpp(177): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::common_type<int,units::kilometres>' being compiled
```

The code in question is:

```
namespace std
{
    template <typename CommonRep, typename Length1, typename Length2>
    struct distance_common_type
    {
    private:
        using gcd_num    = units::detail::greatest_common_divisor<Length1::num, Length2::num>;
        using gcd_den    = units::detail::greatest_common_divisor<Length1::den, Length2::den>;
        using common_rep = typename CommonRep::type;
        using ratio      = std::ratio<gcd_num::value, (Length1::den / gcd_den::value) * Length2::den>;

    public:
        using type = units::distance<common_rep, ratio>;
    };

    template <typename Rep1, typename Length1, typename Rep2, typename Length2>
    struct common_type<units::distance<Rep1, Length1>,
                       units::distance<Rep2, Length2>>
    {
        using type = typename distance_common_type<std::common_type<Rep1, Rep2>,
                                                   Length1,
                                                   Length2>::type;
    };
}

template <
        typename Rep1,
        typename Length1,
        typename Rep2,
        typename Length2>
    constexpr auto operator%(distance<Rep1, Length1> lhs, distance<Rep2, Length2> rhs)
        -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<typename std::common_type<Rep1, Rep2>::type>::value,
                                   typename std::common_type<distance<Rep1, Length1>,
                                                             distance<Rep2, Length2>>::type>::type
    {
        using distance1   = distance<Rep1, Length1>;
        using distance2   = distance<Rep2, Length2>;
        using common_type = typename std::common_type<distance1, distance2>::type;

        return static_cast<common_type>(detail::fmod(static_cast<common_type>(lhs).count(),
                                                     static_cast<common_type>(rhs).count()));
    }

    template <
        typename Rep1,
        typename Length1,
        typename Rep2,
        typename Length2>
    constexpr auto operator%(distance<Rep1, Length1> lhs, distance<Rep2, Length2> rhs)
        -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<typename std::common_type<Rep1, Rep2>::type>::value,
                                   typename std::common_type<distance<Rep1, Length1>,
                                                             distance<Rep2, Length2>>::type>::type
    {
        using distance1   = distance<Rep1, Length1>;
        using distance2   = distance<Rep2, Length2>;
        using common_type = typename std::common_type<distance1, distance2>::type;

        return static_cast<common_type>(static_cast<common_type>(lhs).count() % static_cast<common_type>(rhs).count());
    }
```

AppleClang comlains about the same code for the same reason https://travis-ci.org/bigdavedev/units/jobs/169334303#L100.

I cannot figure out which set of compilers is correct here. Two out of four can compile the above while the other two cannot.

Since the first test uses two instances of units::distance I would expect that the common_type specialization look like:

```
std::common_type<units::distance<double, std::ratio<1>>, units::distance<double, std::kilo>>;
```

which should resolve the common rep as double and thus, compile. In the second case I would expect the common_type specialisation to look like:

```
std::common_type<units::distance<int, std::ratio<1>>, units::distance<double, std::kilo>>;
```

which should resolve the common_rep as double and thus compile. Logically, it would seem, that MSVC and AppleClang are getting this wrong.

Is anybody able to help me to make sense of the error in question?

Comment: The error is from a different part of the code that you didn't show, which is probably something along the lines of `operator/(distance<Rep1, Period1>, Rep2) ->  distance<common_type<Rep1, Rep2>::type, ...>`. Overload resolution causes in `common_type<double, distance<...>>` being instantiated, which - unless the library's `common_type` is SFINAE-friendly - results in a hard error.